# Google Apps Script FileUpload() without FormPanel?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, google-apps-script

I am in the process of building my first application that makes use of Google Apps Script.  I need to have a form that allows the upload of a file to a Google Documents List.  I  currently have this working using code based on the [Google Apps Script FileUpload docmentation](http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/class_fileupload.html) :

```
function doGet(e) { 
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Upload CSV to Sheet");
  var form = app.createFormPanel().setId('frm').setEncoding('multipart/form-data');
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel();
  form.add(formContent);  
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  formContent.add(app.createSubmitButton('Submit'));
  app.add(form);
  return app;
}

function doPost(e) {
  // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

However, I would like to specify my own click handlers for the Submit button and not wait for the POST if possible.  When I tried to change the code above to something like this, the reference to **e.parameter.thefile** is null and does not contain the file blob.

```
function doGet(e) {

  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("Upload CSV to Sheet");
  var formContent = app.createVerticalPanel(); 
  var submitServerHandler = app.createServerClickHandler('submitHandler_');
  formContent.add(app.createFileUpload().setName('thefile'));
  submitServerHandler.addCallbackElement(formContent);  
  formContent.add(app.createButton('Submit').addClickHandler(submitServerHandler));  
  app.add(formContent);
  return app;
}

function submitHandler_(e) {
  // data returned is a blob for FileUpload widget
  var fileBlob = e.parameter.thefile;
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
  app.close();
  return app;
}
```

Is it possible to use the FileUpload control without a FormPanel?  If so, how?  Thanks!

Comment: This question use deprecated classes like DocsList.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use doPost for the file upload to work. You can add more click handlers to the submit  button. If you want a fast response on the UI use a client side handler. Anything you have on the form panel that is named will be passed in e.parameter and you can use hiddens like in a normal html form.

What is it that you want to do? That would help me give you a better answer.

Comment: +1 Thanks for answering.  My goal was to have the file upload as part of a larger data entry form - I was hoping to be able to upload the file when the user clicked an "Upload" button without submitting the rest of the data on the form.

Comment: Maybe this has changed since originally answered - the upload can work from a `doGet()`. (See [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16461925/1677912).)

Answer (score 1):

```
function doGet(e) { 
  var app = UiApp.createApplication(); 
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel().setId('panel');
  var fileUpload = app.createFileUpload().setName('theFile').setId('theFile');
  var handler = app.createServerChangeHandler('uploadfile');
  handler.addCallbackElement(panel);
  fileUpload.addChangeHandler(handler);
  panel.add(fileUpload);
  app.add(panel);
  return app;
} 

function uploadfile(e) 
{ 
// data returned which can be used to create a blob
// assuming mime-type to be a zip file in this example
  var fileBlob = Utilities.newBlob(e.parameter.thefile, "application/zip","myZippedFile.zip" );
  var doc = DocsList.createFile(fileBlob);
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.getElementById('panel').add(app.createLabel('File Uploaded successfully'));
  return app;
}
```

From  https://sites.google.com/site/appsscripttutorial/user-interface/upload-doc

Comment: I've tried this, and it does create a file, but the file is empty, zero bytes.  And the e.parameter for `theFile` returns `undefined`.  I don't think this code works.  Please prove me wrong, because I want to find a way to do this.

Comment: There was a typo ('thefile' instead of 'theFile'), but the created file is still empty. My conclusion is that you must use a FormPanel for file uploads to work.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to uploading files is using createDocsListDialog(). This only allows selecting files from the user's Google Drive, but on the other hand you can do a lot with these files (including working with them without a FormPanel).

(See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/docs-list-dialog for Google's documentation.)

Comment: the question specifically says "...that allows the upload of a file to a Google Documents List".  Opening a file that is already in Drive is not the subject so your answer is irrelevant. Sorry to tell you that, no personal offense ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I've worked a bit more on file uploads, and I wrote some helper functions creating a 'pseudo widget' that can be used in the same way as other UI elements.

I've added it to a collection of helper functions at https://github.com/Itangalo/gash, in case it may help others too.

If you add the code in gash.gs from the site above, you can manage file uploads like this:

```
function doGet() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();

  // We must have a handler set up before creating the file upload.
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('handlerCallback');
  app.add(gash.createFileUpload('myFile', handler));

  app.add(app.createButton('Do something with the file', handler));

  return app;
}

function handlerCallback(eventInfo) {
  // The ID of the file in Google Drive is stored in the parameters.
  var file = DocsList.getFileById(eventInfo.parameter.myFile);
  // The file was uploaded to the trash. Don't forget to un-trash it.
  file.setTrashed(false);

  // Do whatever you want with the file.
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  app.add(app.createLabel('Your file size in bytes: ' + file.getSize()));
  return app;
}
```

There is still a FormPanel in the background, but this way I don't have to touch it.

Comment: As it is, the code you provide does not make a lot of sense...your helper function has to be included in a library to be used like you do. Why not then make your library public and show its key?  Or at least explain that one has to do it prior to use it? Could you clarify pls?  Also:  what is so annoying to use a doGet/doPost  classic structure?  I have no problem using it...:-)

Comment: The library is available at the link I added in the comment, GPL licence and all. (The example is there to show how it can be used, not explain how it is working.) It is not a library shared on GAS, but could be if it matures enough.

The annoying thing about doGet/doPost, at least for me, is that I will have to manage file uploads differently than other input (which I can manage by using standard handlers). Also, the title of this question concerns file uploads without FormPanel.

(I feel a bit trampled. I'm just trying to share the solution I came up with.)

Comment: don't feel tramped... sorry if my comment was obfuscating, it was not my intention ;-) I looked at your link but didn't see the mention of the library, I mainly looked at its code and found it was a lot of work for something that (as I said) didn't ever bother me when I build Ui and forms. My comment was mainly to draw attention on the fact that the code shown here needs the library to be included as a library and would not work without it. PS : now I see that I already commented your post below... you'll begin to think I'm "seeking" you (XD)but I don't! this is a pure coincidence, believe me!

Comment: btw, there are so many bad codes posted here these last days that I was probably a bit irritated...(therefor the inappropriate form of my comment) bad point for me, I'll learn the lesson : keep ZEN ;-) no matter what I read.

Comment: I re-read the gitHub but I can't find any mention of a Library... What am I missing ? do I need a new pair of glasses ? ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up -- appreciated. Zen restored. :-)

There is no extra libraray, only the code in gash.gs. The code in example.gs just shows one way of using it. I'm editing the answer now, so it is clear that gash.gs is required.